# How can I purge all jobs in the JES2 Spool PRINT QUEUE that start with a prefix of XXX older than n days?

Tags: mainframe, zos

I would like to purge all jobs in the JES2 Spool PRINT queue that are older than n days and that start with a prefix of XXX?

I've looked at the JES2 commands and, to be frank, I can't make heads or tails out of the various cancel and purge commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use the following command:
`$pojq,jm=XXX,days>Y`   (where XXX is the job "filter" and Y is # of days)

The above command purges all job output matching the filters, so you may want to further reduce it's range by adding Q=? so you only purge output on a specified class or classes. You can specify multiple classes.
For example: `$pojq,jm=XXX,days>Y,q=abc`

Comment: I read the command and it seems to purge all output including jobs, STCs, TSUs, etc.  Is there a way to only include JOBs ?

Comment: you could use $poj'xxxxx',days>y to limit scope to not include STC's, TSU's.
Where xxxxx is a specific jobname, so in this case you lose the ability to specify a filter with wildcards.

Comment: presumably that requires having a fair amount of authority? Is there a way a developer could do it (or would this work?)

Comment: A typical/common setup would perhaps allow users to purge only their own output.